# No se puede convertir el objeto COM del tipo 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass' C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, deployment, ms-word, clickonce

estoy generando un reporte en Word en mi aplicativo(c# , WindowsForms), y funciona todo bien al ejecutarlo en mi computador, pero cuando lo compilo y lo ejecuto en el computador de otro usuario me sale este error al generar el Word, he intentando instalar/copiar las DLL en el computador del usuario final :

- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Pero no consigo algún resultado.

**Error :**

> No se puede convertir el objeto COM del tipo 
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass'  al tipo de interfaz
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application'.  Ocurrió un error de
>   operación debido a que la llamada QueryInterface en el componente COM 
>   para la interfaz con IID '{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'
>   generó el siguiente error:  Biblioteca no registrada. (Excepción de
>   HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).

Comment: En el equipo del otro usuario está instalado el office? El error que te da parece ser porque la dll no está registrada, lo mas sencillo probablemente sería instalar el office, si no tendrás posiblemente que registrar esas liberías usando [`regsvr32`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regsvr32)

Comment: Si, tiene instalado el Office Professional Plus 2013 [Activado]

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esto](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d34c4f78-46f3-478e-9c44-95ea8461e46f/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-office-interop-word?forum=vsto)

Comment: Gracias al compañero que compartio su solucion pude abrir mi carpeta de opus a excel.. solo tienes que reparar el office

Answer (score 1):

Tuve le mismo problema al importar el contenido de un documento de Word al control RichTextBox, en una PC sin problema en otra, obtenía dicha excepción.

Solo Repararé Office (aunque funcione Word, Excel, etc.) desde el panel de control y ya se resolvió el problema.

Saludos

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Answer (score 1):

Hola tenia el mismo problema y tome como referencia el comentario

> Tuve le mismo problema al importar el contenido de un documento de Word al control RichTextBox, en una PC sin problema en otra, obtenía dicha excepción. Solo Repararé Office (aunque funcione Word, Excel, etc.) desde el panel de control y ya se resolvió el problema.

Y funciono de maravilla.

Solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

1. Entrar al panel de control.
2. Seleccionar la versión de office instalada
3. Dar clic en la opción cambiar
4. Seleccionar reparación rápida.

Después de eso ejecute mi aplicación y funciono sin problema.

VS 2019 con Office 2019